# Avoid repetition, with loop?

Tags: python

I'm learning multiple linear regression, I'm using backward elimination for optimizing my model and python as a programming language.

I'm using three lines of code repeatedly for removing the columns which as significant value >0.05 (i.e p>0.05). I want to apply a loop or a function for those lines so that I can avoid the repetition.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#importing the dataset

dataset=pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')

x=dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values #taking all the lines and cols expect last col(-1)

y=dataset.iloc[:,4].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

lableencoder_x=LabelEncoder()
x[:, 3]=lableencoder_x.fit_transform(x[:, 3])
onehotencoder=OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[3])
x=onehotencoder.fit_transform(x).toarray()

#avoiding dummy variable trap

x=x[:,1:]

#splitig

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(x,y,test_size=1/3, random_state= 0)

#fitting the linear regression to the training set

#linearregression package can do multiple linear regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

regressor=LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred=regressor.predict(x_test)

#bulding optimal model using backwards elimination

import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

x=np.append(arr=np.ones((50,1)).astype(int), values=x,axis=1)

##### below are the repeated lines #####

x_opt=x[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
regressor_ols=sm.OLS(endog=y,exog=x_opt).fit()
regressor_ols.summary()
#column 2 has the p>0.05 so I removed and again optimizing the model
x_opt=x[:,[0,1,3,4,5]]
regressor_ols=sm.OLS(endog=y,exog=x_opt).fit()
regressor_ols.summary()

#column 1 has the p>0.05 so I removed and again optimizing the model

x_opt=x[:,[0,3,4,5]]
regressor_ols=sm.OLS(endog=y,exog=x_opt).fit()
regressor_ols.summary()

#column 4 has the p>0.05 so I removed and again optimizing the model

x_opt=x[:,[0,3,5]]
regressor_ols=sm.OLS(endog=y,exog=x_opt).fit()
regressor_ols.summary()

#column 5 has the p>0.05 so I removed and again optimizing the model

x_opt=x[:,[0,3]]
regressor_ols=sm.OLS(endog=y,exog=x_opt).fit()
regressor_ols.summary()
```

For these lines near the end I want to apply something to avoid repetition.

[This is the dataset I'm using and its name is 50_startUps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvyH7.png)

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly obvious.

```py
for cols in [
        [0,1,2,3,4,5],
        # column 2 has the p>0.05 so I removed and again optimizing the model
        [0,1,3,4,5],
        # column 1 has the p>0.05 so I removed and again optimizing the model
        [0,3,4,5],
        # column 4 has the p>0.05 so I removed and again optimizing the model
        [0,3,5],
        # column 5 has the p>0.05 so I removed and again optimizing the model
        [0,3]]:
    x_opt=x[:,cols]
    regressor_ols=sm.OLS(endog=y,exog=x_opt).fit()
    regressor_ols.summary()
```

Notice also the spelling of "column", in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define a function, and call it in a loop.

Example:

```py
def regressor_with(var_list):
    x_opt=x[:,var_list]
    regressor_ols=sm.OLS(endog=y,exog=x_opt).fit()
    return regressor_ols.summary()
def get_index_of_problem(summary):  
    # pseudo code, depending on your check, 
    # expecting number of summary = number of value in orifinal_list on each change
    for index, value in enumerate(summary):
        if value > 0.05:
            return index
        
original_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
while len(original_list)>0:
    summary = regressor_with(original_list)
    index_n = get_index_of_problem(summary)
    original_list.pop(index_n)
```

Comment: 0,1,2,3,4,5 are the columns in x-model they must be deleted according to there probabulity values dynamically

Comment: @SantoshBurada In that case, you can try `while` loop. Please see my edit.

Comment: ok @ Lê Tư Thành .but it is giving error "TypeError: 'Summary' object is not iterable"

Comment: @SantoshBurada `get_index_of_problem()` is only my pseudocode, you must modify it following your `summary` format and conditions. My code is just a suggestion.

Comment: @ Lê Tư Thành  I'm also searching for how to get the probability value of an index from summary function, But I didn't get the answer for that ,thats whay i posted in stackoverflow. sry if i hurt you...and thanks for your suggestion